# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_variable' when there is no 'get_variable' in the code

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to run [NVidia's face generating demo(Progressive growing GAN)](https://github.com/tkarras/progressive_growing_of_gans) on my remote server in linux. Since the original code is written in tensorflow1.xx, I used `tf_upgrade_v2 --intree ./ProGAN/ --outtree ./ProGAN_v2/  --reportfile ./report.txt` to upgrade the tensorflow into 2.xx in the code. I used tensorflow 2.5.0 in my environment. I am new to tensorflow and deep learning.

However, when running the `import_example.py` script I am getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_example.py", line 17, in <module>
    G, D, Gs = pickle.load(file)
  File "/data01/home/scy0271/run/undergrad/Thorax_GAN-master/ProGAN_v2/tfutil.py", line 572, in __setstate__
    self._init_graph()
  File "/data01/home/scy0271/run/undergrad/Thorax_GAN-master/ProGAN_v2/tfutil.py", line 477, in _init_graph
    out_expr = self._build_func(*self.input_templates, is_template_graph=True, **self.static_kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 179, in G_paper
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_variable'
```

I searched in the code and there is no `get_variable` without a prefix of `tf.compat.v1.`. In the function `G_paper` of `networks.py`, there is no `get_variable` without a prefix of `tf.compat.v1.`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The API which you are using `tf.compat.v1.get_variable` was designed for TensorFlow v1.

Pleas checkout this migration [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) for your reference.

For the latest Tensorflow version, use this following equivalent :

[tf.variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable)

```
tf.Variable(
    initial_value=None,
    trainable=None,
    validate_shape=True,
    caching_device=None,
    name=None,
    variable_def=None,
    dtype=None,
    import_scope=None,
    constraint=None,
    synchronization=tf.VariableSynchronization.AUTO,
    aggregation=tf.compat.v1.VariableAggregation.NONE,
    shape=None,
    experimental_enable_variable_lifting=True
)
```

Should you need to transform your model to the latest TF version, check the model migration guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/model_mapping).